# Internet access in Japan

Tags: japan, cellphones, pre-pay, internet

What options are there in terms of prepaid Internet services? Are the charges reasonable? I will be there for no more than two weeks so prepaid seems to be the sensible option.

Comment: It looks like this is essentially a duplicate of another question we have on here.  If I'm mistaken, please flag and let me know, but for now I'm marking it as such.

Comment: Not quite the same -- he's interested specifically in Internet access, not an all-purpose phone.

Comment: @Switchkick Did you make your trip? Did it work? Look at this: http://300.wi2.co.jp/en/price/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two good options.

If you're OK with relying on Wifi hotspots, instead of needing 100% coverage, the best option is to sign up for a **[Wi2 300 monthly account](https://wi2.co.jp/jp/personal/300/reg/)**.  (Available in Japanese only, and not to be confused with the far more expensive [travel plans](http://wi2.co.jp/en/300/) for tourists!)   For Y362/month, you get access to their own hotspots plus the Yahoo!BB and UQ networks, for a total of over <s>70,000</s> 200,000 access points around Japan. (See [FAQ](http://300.wi2.co.jp/contents/1/?tp=faq&locale=en#faq1).) They provide a "Wi2Connect4" app for iOS devices to ease the pain of typing in network IDs etc. And yes, you can cancel with no strings attached once you get home and pay only a single month's fee — at time of writing they even have a "first month free" promo.

That said, while the number sounds impressive and [the map](http://300.wi2.co.jp/wi2area/?latitude=35.675949&longitude=139.767036&locale=en) looks packed as well, you can't count on having a hotspot whenever you want one.  In particular, the "premium" hotspots (Wi2Premium, orange on map) incur an extra charge of ¥100/hr.

If you want actual 4G mobile internet on your cellphone available anywhere, the cheapest reasonable option I'm aware of is the **[B-Mobile 1 month, 1 GB prepaid](http://japanprepaid.hostingsiteforfree.com/)**, but it's a lot pricier at Y3450 and a little harder to find, although Yodobashi and Bic Camera both stock it.

Comment: Hey, it says that Y380/month is for people that lives in Japan!! (http://300.wi2.co.jp/en/price/)

Comment: Yes, but there's no verification of any kind, you can punch in any old Japanese address.

Comment: How is this old Japanese address thing?

Comment: Hmm?  I meant that you can enter anything you like in the address field, it is not checked.  Your hotel's address, the Imperial Palace, etc.

Comment: Currently on wi2 right now. Our group was hoping wi2 was ubiquitous but that's very far from reality. We've been all over Tokyo and were only able to get access maybe half an hour every day. And that's being generous. I suppose you get what you pay for.

Comment: Well, they're wifi hot spots, not a mobile phone network...  but I found that, if you plan ahead a bit, it's not too hard to find one within striking distance of pretty much wherever you go -- and if you can spot a McDonalds, you're online.