# Internet in Japan

Tags: budget, japan, internet, pre-pay

During travel in Japan I would like to have internet in my laptop and Ipad. What is not very expensive solution to do that? Is there any prepaid internet in Japan? I Think I will need 1GB

Comment: How much data would you need? 100MB? 10GB?

Comment: I think I will need 1Gb

Comment: Which country are you coming from? Do you need a 3G connection or can it be tied to WLAN accesspoints?

Comment: I'm from Latvia. I'm interested in both - 3G and WLAN

Comment: See also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/internet-access-in-japan

Answer (score 11):

If you would install a [FON router](http://corp.fon.com/#what-is-fon) at home, you have free access to FON spots in Japan. The [coverage](http://maps.fon.com) seems okay in some regions.

Answer (score 9):

There are several different companies in Japan that rent or sell pre-paid SIM cards and portable Wifi Routers:

- [mb.softbank.jp](http://mb.softbank.jp/en/start/contents/plan_short.html)
- [pupuru.com](http://www.pupuru.com/en/service/emobile/)
- [bmobile.ne.jp](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/english/u300_visitor.html)
- [rentafonejapan.com](http://www.rentafonejapan.com/Mobile-Internet.html)
- [sallysrental.com](http://www.sallysrental.com/)
- [econnectjapan.com](http://www.econnectjapan.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Not 'prepaid' per se, but Starbucks in Japan now offers free Wi-fi and an English log-in page. I've found many of the FON hotspots to be inaccessible even though I have a FON router at home as many are sponsored by Softbank and hence need to be accessed through a Softbank 3G connection to add the appropriate profile / cookies.