# Using Wifi in Japan

Tags: japan, wifi

I'm traveling to Japan in June and just wanted to ask whether I should bring my iPhone/iPad to access wifi. I remember from several years ago that it was quite hard to use unless I went to a Starbucks. Is this still the case? Can I purchase a 2 week wifi plan for my iPhone?

Comment: You want to buy a wifi plan or a Data Plan?

Comment: If you mean wifi, of course, take it with you. If you mean data plan, it depends on which model of phone you have (GSM vs CDMA), whether it's unlocked, and maybe other factors.

Comment: It would be nice to also find some tricks to help find free Wi-Fi with free electricity. I'm going to face this problem soon when I leave my guesthouse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few options.

- **Starbucks** as you mention already offers free wifi (but you need to confirm via email first, which can be a pain)
- **NTT East** offers a [free 14-day Wifi access card](http://flets.com/freewifi/index.html) for foreign tourists that lets you access Flets Wifi spots all over Tokyo. You can get one of these on presentation of your passport at any of these [distribution points.](http://flets.com/freewifi/spot.html)
- **Pocket Wifi** units are also available, allowing you to connect devices to a mobile internet 'dongle' that connects to the 4G network. These can be delivered to Narita and other airports. One company offering them is [Global Advanced Comm](http://globaladvancedcomm.com/pocketwifi.html)
- **b-mobile data SIMs** can give you [3G access on your unlocked iPhone](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/english/devices.html).
- **7spot** at 7 Eleven convenience stores (they're everywhere) offer free wifi once [registered](https://webapp.7spot.jp/internets/) (with [English registration help](http://www.7spot.jp/register_form_english/pc_out.gif))
- **FamilyMart**, another convenience store chain, also offers free-wifi. Again, registration in Japanese but someone has posted a [comprehensive English explanation of the process](http://konaka-residence.com/convenience-store-family-mart-start-free-wifi/).
- **JR East** railways also offers [free wifi at certain JR East stations](http://www.jreast.co.jp/e/pdf/free_wifi_02_e.pdf), but again requires registration

These I think are the easiest options, but there are more - see [Japan-Guide's breakdown](http://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2279.html) (a quick Google of the service name + 'English' will usually find you an explanation even if the main site is in Japanese).

Comment: The pocket wifi seems really good, and I hadn't come across it before. I might consider that! Thanks!!

Comment: Awesome, glad to be of help. They're quite expensive but EXTREMELY fast. Enjoy your trip!

Comment: Good list of possibilities.
For rental WiFi access my experience with [Rentafone Japan](http://www.rentafonejapan.com/) has always been very good. All instructions in English and rental units with English menus.

Comment: 2023 update: I may be wrong, but I just spent 2.5 months in Japan and never found a Wi-Fi signal I could connect to at any 7-Eleven or any FamilyMart. Perhaps they got rid of them during the pandemic, or that may just be a coincidence. On the other had, Lawsons now always has free Wi-Fi and it is extremely reliable and easy to connect to. Just two clicks I think.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, I'd bring the iPad, but you will definitely have to plan ahead since 100% no strings attached free wifi is rare as hen's teeth in Japan.

Two main points:

1. Make sure your lodging offers free wifi for guests.  Almost all business hotels and backpacker-y places do, but large chain hotels will charge an arm and a leg, and ryokan/minshuku usually won't have it.
2. Consider signing up for [Wi2 300](https://service.wi2.ne.jp/wi2net/reg/2/?locale=en), discussed in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/internet-access-in-japan).  TL;DR: ¥380/month gets you access to ~70,000 hot spots, and you can cancel after the first month.  Note that, while that number sounds huge, it's actually not that much for a country of 100 million; it's worth studying the list in advance so you can figure out the chain stores (mostly Lawson & McDonalds) where you can get online.

Comment: In 2023, free Wi-Fi is now a lot more common in Japan than it has ever been before. Every Lawson convenience store has free Wi-Fi you can use for I think four times per day 1 hour each time, with just a couple of clicks to connect. Coffee chains such as Starbucks and Tully's don't require passwords. If you're travelling by road, almost every Service Area, Parking Area, and Michi-no-Eki has free Wi-Fi. Many other free signals are now around that require filling a small form including email address but not phone number or passport number.