# Where to get data-only SIM in Japan

Tags: japan, cellphones, data-plans

I have an unlocked North American (Canada) iPhone 5s, where can I buy a data only SIM card in Japan ? I'm not interested in renting nor in a voice plan, I'll be staying for 4 weeks.

I'll be landing in Tokyo, so preferably around there. Can I get them from the airport somewhere ?
I'm assuming I won't have problems with the network/frequencies, am I correct ?

Comment: Related (Mostly wifi, but also data-sim): http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/25650/28202

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some providers such as [b-mobile](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/payg_sim/travelers_to_japan.html) and [eConnect](https://www.econnectjapan.com/products/sim/) offer SIM pre-orders: you order it before leaving and it is shipped to your hotel or the [airport post office](http://www.bmobile.ne.jp/english/aps_top.html) for you to pick up. Note that the post office at Haneda airport is located in the domestic Terminal 1, so you would need to take a (free) shuttle bus to go there from the international terminal. (At Narita there is one post office in each terminal.)

b-mobile, as well as [so-net](http://www.so-net.ne.jp/prepaid/en/) and probably some others are sold in physical stores, of which you can find a list on their websites.

Finally, OCN recently introduced [SIM vending machines](http://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2015/07/24/business/tech/z-japans-new-sim-card-vending-machines/#.VdyYV3ugp98) at Narita airport (one in each terminal).

Comment: I've used eConnect before and got the SIM-card delivered to my hotel. We didn't have any issues at all using that service.

Comment: You have to have physical address for voice line only. I was able to buy a data only prepaid sim card in the regular electronics store near Shinjuku station.

Answer (score 3):

There were no problems to buy the data only SIM card right in the Osaka-Kansai airport and I even have seen SIM card vending machines in Kyoto.

You need to know how to configure mobile data access point, going into device settings you do not need to touch when swapping one EU card for another. It is not complex, just unusual.  While English instructions are sold with the card, the seller will not touch your phone, you must configure it yourself. Also, you obviously need a recent and unlocked phone, better dual SIM.